# Spring MVC 415 error when posting form

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, web

Getting 415 error when doing POST request.
This is my form:

```
<c:url value="/createOrUpdate" var="actionUrl"/>
  <form  action="${actionUrl}" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <table class="editor silver">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Edit advert details</th>
        <input type="number" hidden value="${advert.id}" name="id"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Owner:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" disabled value="${advert.owner}" name="owner"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Publication date:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="datetime" disabled value="${advert.publicationDate}" name="publicationDate"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Select rubric</td>
        <td>
          <select name="rubric">
            <option value="sale" selected>Sale</option>
            <option value="buy">Buy</option>
            <option value="lease">Lease</option>
            <option value="services">Services</option>
            <option value="dating">Dating</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter header:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="${advert.header}" name="header"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter text:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="${advert.text}" name="text"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

And this is controller where i'm doing request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createOrUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ModelAndView editAdvert(@RequestBody Advert advert) {//some actions
```

Advert is a simple POJO with getters and setters:

```
private long id;

private String owner;

private Date publicationDate;

private String rubric;

private String header;

private String text;
```

What i'm doing wrong? 
p.s. As i understand spring should map that 'name-fields' into fields of POJO. Right?
**Added** Ok, i found that some values didn't send in form. I checked console in browser and now it's ok, but still i get 415 error.

Comment: You can use ModelAttribute instead of RequestBody.  RequestBody consume json,xml. remove application/x-www-form-urlencoded because it is already default type. if you want to use @requestbody then you post your form data as json, Using a JavaScript-library like JQuery, you would post a JSON data with Content-Type:application/json. and use jackson-lib convert json to java object easily.

Comment: But now i get error 400 - bad request

Comment: the problem might be send date. focus how to send date spring mvc. You can use DateTimeFormat [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581208/http-status-400-bad-request-issue/42587545#42587545) or InıtBinder

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`. RequestBody consume json,xml. Remove application/x-www-form-urlencoded because it is already default type.

If you want to use `@Requestbody` then you post your form data as json, using a JavaScript-library like JQuery, you would post a JSON data with Content-Type:application/json. And use jackson-lib convert json to java object easily.

*400 - bad request*

The problem might be date sending. Focus on how to send date spring mvc. You can use `@DateTimeFormat` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581208/http-status-400-bad-request-issue) or `@InıtBinder`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in date conversion.
Change `@RequestBody to @MadelAttribute` and put `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private Date publicationDate;` 
to a model